# Disabling QPushButton before a task

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I created `QPushButton` and made a connection to a specific task. In addition to this task, I would like to disable this `QPushButton`. Thus I add `mypushbutton.setEnabled(False)` just before the task, but it won't work as I expected, the button is disabled after my task is done. However, when I remove my task, it works.

Comment: If the task is blocking, you may want to consider threading it to avoid blocking the event loop.

Comment: right after `setEnabled(false)` and before "run my task" try calling `mypushbutton.repaint()`.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do:**

```
mypushbutton.setEnabled(False);
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
// do something
```

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents

***Updated with doc comments***

Comment: You have created local event loop which even doesn't start and does nothing. The way to process pending events of main event loop is to call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`.